# Good way to approximate a floating point number

Tags: delphi, approximation

I have a program that solves equations and sometimes the solutions `x1` and `x2` are numbers with a lot of decimal numbers. For example when `Δ = 201` (Δ = discriminant) the square root gives me a floating point number.

I need a good approximation of that number because I also have a function that converts it into a fraction. So I thought to do this:

```
 Result := FormatFloat('0.#####', StrToFloat(solx1));
```

The `solx1` is a double. In this way, the number '456,9067896' becomes '456,90679'.

My question is this: if I approximate in this way, the fraction of `456,9067896` will be correct (and the same) if I have `456,90679`?

Comment: I cannot make any sense of this.

Comment: Did you even understand what I asked then?

Comment: No, I've no idea what you are asking. Downvoting random answers doesn't achieve a right lot.

Comment: Alberto, sounds like you need to read this:
"What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

In your case you probably want to use symbolic math libraries and bignum types, and rolling your own bignum types is not a job for the fainthearted.

Comment: @Warren Certainly does not sound to me like symbolic math is needed here. Good old finite precision floating point seems fine.

Comment: You don't think he's going to hit fractional values that are not precisely expressable in binary, causing him grief?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare two floating point values with a given precision, just use the `SameValue()` function [from Math unit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Math.SameValue) or its sibbling `CompareValue().`

```
if SameValue(456.9067896, 456.90679, 1E-5) then ...
```

You can specify the precision on which the comparision will take place.

Or you can use a `currency` value, which has fixed arithmetic precision of 4 digits. So, it won't have rounding issue any more. But you can not do all mathematic computation with it (huge or tiny numbers are not handled properly): its main use is for accounting computations.

You should better never use `string` representations to compare floats, since it may be very confusing, and do not have good rounding abilities.

Comment: Personally I'd just as soon write abs(x-y)<eps which is shorter and more explicit for the benefit of the next reader of the code. Even if that next reader is you!!

Comment: Now, what are you talking about in your discussion of Currency? You suggest that using currency avoids rounding. Your language is imprecise there. In any case, surely there's no use at all for decimal fixed point in numerical algos.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Simple `abs(x-y)<eps` won't work in some cases, which SameValue() performs properly when you are working with a `eps` value close to the stored precision itself (see how Math.SameValue is implemented). BTW those functions would benefit for inlining.

Comment: That depends on the definition of "won't work". My definition would imply that `SameValue` does not work. It's implementation is somewhat bogus.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez SameValue uses relative error, which is abs(x-y)/abs(x) < eps. This is indeed the correct interpretation of the eps value, which indicated the smallest number such that 1 + eps != 1

Comment: @Giulio You cannot say that relative error is correct. It's correct if you want relative error. It's incorrect if you want absolute error. And are you sure SameValue uses relative error?

Comment: Is absolute error and relative error discussed in that What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point paper?

Comment: @WarrenP Sounds to be the case, [if you are talking about this paper](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

> the fraction of `456,9067896` will be correct (and the same) if I have `456,90679`?

No, because `0.9067896` is unequal to `0.90679`.

But why do you want to round the numbers? Just let them be as they are. Shorten them only for visual representation.

Comment: Sometimes I have numbers that ends with 1E15 for example, and they give me errors when I put them in my function.

Comment: Don't convert the numbers to strings for calculations.

Comment: @AlbertoRossi - this is now starting to sound like your real problem.  Suggest you try posting a new question explaining the problem with your function and what, exactly, the errors are.

Answer (score 3):

If you are worried about complete correctness of the result, you should not use floating point numbers at all, because floating points are, by definition, a rounding of real numbers. Only the first 5-6 decimal digits of a 32-bit floating point are generally reliable, the following ones are unreliable, due to machine error.

If you want complete precision, you should be using symbolic maths (rational numbers and symbolic representation for irrational/imaginary numbers).

Comment: Nice answer, thank you. So at least I should approximate to 5 decimal digits?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to approximate at all? Why do you think this answer suggests approximation to 5 decimal digits? I trust you realise that floating point IEEE754 as you use it is binary and not decimal.

Comment: @AlbertoRossi you should not approximate at all. All the approximations you perform is further loss of precision, which adds to the loss of precision due to the conversion to floating point.

Comment: -1 What are you talking about? 32 bit 'double' values give from 15–17 significant decimal digits precision. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: @Arnaud He's talking about 32 bit single precision. You are talking about 64 bit double precision.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right - my mistake! But even `single` gives from 6 to 9 significant decimal digits precision - more than "5-6". If a decimal string with at most 6 significant decimal is converted to IEEE 754 single precision and then converted back to the same number of significant decimal, then the final string should match the original; and if an IEEE 754 single precision is converted to a decimal string with at least 9 significant decimal and then converted back to single, then the final number must match the original.